# Ihave developed an app which perfectly runs from API 18 to 28 but it craches below API 26 i dont understand how to solve this problem

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

This has error in logcat 1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5nOz.png
   The program flow goes from splash--->player--->MainActivity and also an about app activity please help me out.Splash.xml It mainly contains error!.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".splash">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="103dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="216dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="183dp"
        android:layout_height="158dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/t1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="268dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/aldrich"
        android:text="TIC TAC TOE"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

splash.java

```
package com.vishwas.tictactoe;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        if (!isConnected(splash.this)) buildDialog(splash.this).show();
        else {


            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(splash.this, player.class));
                    finish();
                }
            }, 4100);


        }

    }

    public boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netinfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netinfo != null && netinfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

            if ((mobile != null && mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting()) || (wifi != null && wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting())) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public AlertDialog.Builder buildDialog(Context c) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
        builder.setTitle("No Internet Connection!");
        builder.setMessage("You need to have internet connection to play this game.\n Press Ok to Exit!");

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        }).setCancelable(false);
        return builder;
    }

}
```

Actvity_player.xml It was also containing error but now its gone

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context=".player">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/abtapp2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="71dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="68dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bt_mainback"
        android:onClick="abt"
        android:text="About App"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.468"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton5" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7866343935318771/3173472761"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="364dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcornersedittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="316dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Enter Name Of Player 2:"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.514"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="168dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Enter Name Of Player 1:"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="212dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcornersedittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:onClick="pass"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.706"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/arr" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

> player.java

```
package com.vishwas.tictactoe;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class player extends AppCompatActivity {
private AdView myAdView;
private EditText et1;
    private EditText et2;
private ImageButton ibt1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        // Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-7866343935318771~9805549476 banner2
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-7866343935318771~9805549476");
        AdView adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-7866343935318771/3173472761");
        myAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView3);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        myAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        //
        et1 = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        et2 = findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        ibt1 = findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    }

    public void pass(View view)
    {
        if(et1.getText().toString().equals(et2.getText().toString()))
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(player.this);
            builder.setMessage("Both Name can't be equal!!!").setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
        else
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            String p1 = et1.getText().toString();
            String p2 = et2.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra("player1", p1);
            intent.putExtra("player2", p2);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(player.this);
        builder.setMessage("Do you really want to Exit?").setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                player.super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel",null).setCancelable(false);
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    public void abt(View view)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,about.class));
    }
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bkcolor"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="47dp"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view_p2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_p1"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="47dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_reset"
            android:layout_width="116dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bt_mainback"
            android:text="reset"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="121dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_00"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_01"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_02"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="123dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_10"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_11"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_12"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="138dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_20"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_21"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_22"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:freezesText="true"
            android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
            android:textSize="60sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7866343935318771/5991207790" />


</LinearLayout>
```

> MainActivity.java

```
package com.vishwas.tictactoe;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private AdView myAdView;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private final Button[][] buttons = new Button[3][3];

    private boolean player1Turn = true;

    private int roundCount;

    String p1up;
    String p2up;
    String p1;
    String p2;

    public int player1Points;
    public int player2Points;

    public TextView textViewPlayer1;
    public TextView textViewPlayer2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textViewPlayer1 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_p1);
        textViewPlayer2 = findViewById(R.id.text_view_p2);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
         p1 = intent.getStringExtra("player1");
         p2 = intent.getStringExtra("player2");

        textViewPlayer1.setText(p1+":");
        textViewPlayer2.setText(p2+":");

        // Sample AdMob app ID:ca-app-pub-7866343935318771~9805549476 banner1
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-7866343935318771~9805549476");
        AdView adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-7866343935318771/5991207790");
        myAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        myAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        // Sample AdMob app ID: ca-app-pub-7866343935318771~9805549476 InterstitialAd
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-7866343935318771/4056746387");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new  AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                // Load the next interstitial.
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }

        });
        //

        //



        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                String buttonID = "button_" + i + j;
                int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonID, "id", getPackageName());
                buttons[i][j] = findViewById(resID);
                buttons[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        }

        Button buttonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
        buttonReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                resetGame();
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!((Button) v).getText().toString().equals("")) {
            return;
        }

        if (player1Turn) {
            ((Button) v).setText("X");
        } else {
            ((Button) v).setText("O");
        }

        roundCount++;

        if (checkForWin()) {
            if (player1Turn) {
                player1Wins();
            } else {
                player2Wins();
            }
        } else if (roundCount == 9) {
            draw();
        } else {
            player1Turn = !player1Turn;
        }

    }

    private boolean checkForWin() {
        String[][] field = new String[3][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                field[i][j] = buttons[i][j].getText().toString();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (field[i][0].equals(field[i][1])
                    && field[i][0].equals(field[i][2])
                    && !field[i][0].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (field[0][i].equals(field[1][i])
                    && field[0][i].equals(field[2][i])
                    && !field[0][i].equals("")) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (field[0][0].equals(field[1][1])
                && field[0][0].equals(field[2][2])
                && !field[0][0].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }

        if (field[0][2].equals(field[1][1])
                && field[0][2].equals(field[2][0])
                && !field[0][2].equals("")) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void player1Wins() {
        player1Points++;
        Toast.makeText(this, p1+"wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        p1up = String.valueOf(player1Points);
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
    }

    public void player2Wins() {
        player2Points++;
        Toast.makeText(this, p2+"wins!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        p2up = String.valueOf(player2Points);
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
    }

    public void draw() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Draw!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        resetBoard();
    }

    public void updatePointsText() {
        textViewPlayer1.setText(p1+":"+p1up);
        textViewPlayer2.setText(p2+":"+p2up);
    }

    private void resetBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                buttons[i][j].setText("");
            }
        }

        roundCount = 0;
        player1Turn = true;
    }

    private void resetGame() {
        player1Points = 0;
        player2Points = 0;
        p1up="0";
        p2up="0";
        updatePointsText();
        resetBoard();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putInt("roundCount", roundCount);
        outState.putInt("player1Points", player1Points);
        outState.putInt("player2Points", player2Points);
        outState.putBoolean("player1Turn", player1Turn);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        roundCount = savedInstanceState.getInt("roundCount");
        player1Points = savedInstanceState.getInt("player1Points");
        player2Points = savedInstanceState.getInt("player2Points");
        player1Turn = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("player1Turn");
    }

}

> here is the about app activity file which i think that is not creating any error
  > This app runs perfectly on Nougat and Android Pie but it does crashes when it is un on APi Level less than 26 Though the min sdk is 18 and max is 28
```

This app is about tic tac toe game , the problem is that when app is installed and i click on it the app crashes and does not open in Marshmallow but it finely runs on Api greater than 25

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. Also, please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569), and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

but when i run your code, app is running well on lollipop and marshmallow version both.

you can see in your error image cause of error is shown "inflating issue".means imageview is not able to inflate provided image.

note:- in activity_splash.xml

you uses `app:srcCompat` attribute in imageview but it is only supported by after lollipop android version. so if you are targetting your app for api version 18 to 28
then this will be not run below api 21(lollipop).

Solution:-

first of all try to replace `app:srcCompat="@drawable/t1"` by `android:src="@drawable/t1"`

if this solution will not work then check your build version, compiledversion target version in your  app gradle.

activity_splash--

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Splash">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="103dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="216dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="183dp"
        android:layout_height="158dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="268dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="TIC TAC TOE"
        android:textColor="#00a4e4"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```